# Why does System.Uri break my url?

Tags: c#, http

I have the  following C# code `Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/query?param=%E2%80%AE");` and `uri` interprets it like `http://localhost/query?param=` instead of `http://localhost/query?param=%E2%80%AE`. As a result http web server gets `http://localhost/query?param=` (without value of this parameter). Why does it break my url and how can I create `HttpWebRequest` correctly using my `http://localhost/query?param=%E2%80%AE`?

P.S. I have got the `%E2%80%AE` using `System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString((char)8238))`.

Comment: `%E2%80%AE` is U+202E *Right to left override* which is not a printable character

Comment: @AlexK. The main problem is that HttpWebRequest doesn't send the %E2%80%AE. So the problem isn't in ToString(), but is in Uri itself.

Answer (score 1):

`ToString()` will try to render the uri as a string. i.e., it will unescape escaped characters.  However the escaped sequence `%E2%80%AE` is not printable.

Use the `AbsoluteUri` instead.

```
var uriStr = uri.AbsoluteUri; // "http://localhost/query?param=%E2%80%AE"
```

Comment: AbsolutUri also doesn't containts `%E2%80%AE`. The main idea I wated to say is that uri interprets my url without `%E2%80%AE` and therefore HttpWebRequest makes request without `%E2%80%AE` (I see request without `%E2%80%AE` in server logs  and my web application can't find the value of this parameter).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of mis-using of the methods exposed.

- ToString() method, as derived from very first ancestor, Object, is a way to provide some printable form of the given object instance. It's not meant to be instance identity nor full serialization of all internal fields.
- Uri class is designed as a URI parser/composer/dissector so it has various methods to merge or split given URI strings to get server name, local path etc. So if you need URI as a whole thing you have to use "Uri.AbsolutePath Property" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The main problem is that HttpWebRequest doesn't send the `%E2%80%AE`. So the problem isn't in ToString(), but is in Uri itself.